# What technologies came to the PC world from High Performance Computing?

Tags: history, hpc

Recently I came to think about the technologies that supercomputers gave to the modern PCs. I found out that the instruction pipelining appeared in one of the first CDC machines and parallelism was certainly a super-computer hallmark of all the times. But it seems that such "features" like co-processors and cache-memory were initially invented for the "mainstream" computers.

Can you help me to sort this out and name the technologies that came to our desktops and laptops from the supercomputing (and maybe name the ones that *surprisingly* didn't)?

Comment: I am going to say this is wiki material.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, home computers!

If it wasn't for the early super computers, we probably wouldn't have any of the technologies we have now.

Anyway,

[From Wikipedia -
Technologies developed for supercomputers include:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer)

```
* Vector processing
* Liquid cooling
* Non-Uniform Memory Access (NUMA)
* Striped disks (the first instance of what was later called RAID)
* Parallel filesystems
```